# Xcode 7.3 IOS 8.3 Simulator can't connect to internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, connection, ios-simulator

I am currently working on a project in Xcode 7.3 and only the IOS 8.3 simulator cannot access the internet.  I have tried rebooting it, reseting it, closing it, and restating the whole computer.  Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console window? You might need to check the App transport security settings, and make sure its set to allow arbitrary loads.

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings, `Info.plist` target properties you might need to set the `App Transport Security Settings` to `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

According to Apple's ATS you should use HTTPS, but you can modify the info.plist.

[image]

In WWDC 2016, Apple says :

> it will continue to tighten access restrictions on common iOS in HTTP
>   10 and macOS 10.12

.